# Error NULL pam handle passed during cron DB backup

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron, database-backups

In my `crontab -e` I have:

```
*/5 * * * *  path/cron.sh
```

In my cron.sh I have :

```
exec('mysqldump --user =root --password=pass--host=IP dbname > /path/$(date +\%F)_full_myDB.sql');
```

And when i check cron log like `cat /var/log/cron` I get in last few lines :

```
Oct 25 09:05:01 www CROND[32566]: (root) CMD (/path/cron.sh)
Oct 25 09:10:01 www CROND[32610]: (root) CMD (/path/cron.sh)
Oct 25 09:15:01 www CROND[32665]: (root) CMD (/path/cron.sh)
Oct 25 09:20:01 www CROND[32711]: (root) CMD (/path/cron.sh)
Oct 25 09:25:01 www CROND[32760]: (root) CMD (/path/cron.sh)
Oct 25 09:30:01 www CROND[358]: (root) CMD (/path/cron.sh)
Oct 25 09:30:46 www crontab[370]: (root) BEGIN EDIT (root)
Oct 25 09:33:02 www crontab[370]: (root) END EDIT (root)
Oct 25 09:33:02 www crontab[370]: PAM pam_end: NULL pam handle passed
```

I was having this search `cron log NULL pam handle passed` but the where not specific on how to fix this error.

Any idea on how to fix is appreciated

UPDATE:

When I run `mysqldump --user =root --password=pass--host=IP dbname > /path/$(date +\%F)_full_myDB.sql` directly in terminal I get:

I get in the file that was created :

> Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
>
> mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'XXXXX' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

Even if I using the correct password

> Added all privileges for user on the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the cron service and is a known bug reported for version "`cronie-1.4.11-17.El7`"

For more info, refer: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1479064